# change dynamic checkbox value generated by php using jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

The checkbox value has been set dynamically through php

```
<ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="1">Politics         
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[1][1]" value="2">International</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[1][2]" value="2">National</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="2">Views</li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="3">Sport            
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[3][1]" value="2">Volleyball</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[3][2]" value="2">Cricket</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Now, can I remove checkbox value using jquery ? I want to remove value of only `menu[]` which has `submenu[][]`. For example, I am setting these `menu[]` checkboxes readonly using following way.

```
$('li:has(> ul)').find('[name="menu[]"]').click(false);
```

Now I want to add this trick, but doesn't work

```
$('li:has(> ul)').find('[name="menu[]"]').val('');
```

```js
  // Here value is inserted using jquery
$('input[name="project"]').val("Good Fish");

  // But this is not working
$('li:has(> ul)').find('[name="menu[]"]').val('');

// This is working
$('li:has(> ul)').find('[name="menu[]"]').click(false);



$('[name="menu[]"] + ul input').click(function(){
  $(this).closest("ul").prev("input").prop("checked", ($(this).closest("ul").find("input:checked").length > 0));
 });
  $(document).on('submit','#form',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
  if($("[name='menu[]']:checked").length == 0){
   alert('Missing Menu');
   return false;
  }
  else {
      alert('Success')
  }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="1">Politics
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[1][1]" value="2">International</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[1][2]" value="2">National</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="2">Views</li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" name="menu[]" value="3">Sport
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[3][1]" value="2">Volleyball</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" name="submenu[3][2]" value="2">Cricket</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
<input type="text" name="project"><br/>

<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: added a snippet using your sample looks good to me

Comment: can you create fiddle?

Comment: @BhumiShah there is a snippet in the OP

Comment: @BhumiShah, Please see updated snippet, now I can clarify my problem.

Comment: @guradio, I've edited snippet, thanks

Comment: @AnandHmt: see my answer!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work

```
$('li:has(> ul)').find('[name*="menu"]').val('');
```

DEMO: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/zaJreN